# Windshield washer fluid for sticky bugs

Tags: windshield-wipers, windshield-washer

Driving at night and in rural areas I pickup a lot of BIG sticky bugs on the windshield. Even with new wipers on the vehicle I often cannot wash/wipe the bugs off sufficiently while going down the road. Are some washer fluids better at removing sticky bugs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the real key to getting the bugs off is, **the shorter they are on the windshield, the easier they come off the windshield**. If you are in a swarm, I understand this can use a lot of washer fluid and will keep the wipers in the on position a lot. Been there; done that. ( *Try travelling in southern Virginia in the summer time at dusk and see the green glow of lightning bugs as they **cover** the windshield.* )

Something which may help you in the future is to apply a product like [Rain-X](http://www.rainx.com/product/glass-water-repellents-cleaners/rainx-original-glass-treatment/#.VSbf8_nF98E). It says on their product page:

> **Product Features**
>
> - Improve all-weather visibility, safety and driving comfort
> - Helps easily remove frost, ice, salt, mud and **bugs**

This along with the [windshield washer fluid](http://www.rainx.com/product/windshield-washer-fluid/rain-x-2-in-1-windshield-washer-fluid/#.VSbhNfnF98E) to help the repellent part stay good on your windshield will help tremendously with removing bugs when the go splat. Personal experience with the product allows me to state this is a good product.

***NOTE:*** I have no affiliation with the product nor the company which manufactures it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is special windshield washer fluid that is designed specifically to remove the remains of bugs from your windshield.

I don't know what the active ingredient is in these formula's.  I have used this fluid and did not seem to do any harm to the paint of my vehicle either.

All the major auto parts stores have several brands of this type of washer fluid on their shelves.

My own experience is that it works pretty good.  Better than water.